# bounce animation using constructor?

Tags: javascript, event-delegation, dom-events

[image: This is my company logo]

I want to give a bounce animation to each individual hair on mouseover.the animation part is done on the first hair,but i don`t want to give events to each and every hair image.
So here is my question,*I am using constructor* in my javascript code.Is it possible that I create a method in my prototype and make instances of it? So basiclly **I dont want to fire 10 events or 10 addEventListeners**,I want a smart way out of this.
How do I complete my task,as in every hair should bounce on mouseover of itself only

My code:
HTML:

```
 <div class="main">
<div class="hair">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair1" width="13" height="40" >
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair2" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair3" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair4" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair5" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair6" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair7" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair8" width="13" height="40">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair9" width="13" height="40">
</div>
    <div class="face">
        <img src="images/ec_logo.png">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(){
    hair=function (){
        return this;
    };

    hair.prototype={
        bounce:function(){
 //code for some bounce animation
        }
    };
})();
document.getElementById('hair??').addEventListener("mouseover",???,false);????????//this is the part i am confused about,how to give same animation to every single hair by using object instances???
```

Comment: Try to use jquery animate

Comment: i don`t have a problem with animation,that`s fine...i am just asking how to invoke every hair for the same action,like when my mouseover is on hair no.2 then only 2nd hair should bounce

Comment: give a common class to each hair,attach the mouseover event handler to the class.In the event handler , use $(this).id and animate using that id

Comment: so in my html,i have to do this mouseover=function_bounce(this.id) for every hair???or i have to write addEventListener 10 times for every hair???

Comment: you don't have to write an event listener for each hair.Give a common class like 

`<img src="images/single.png" id="hair1" width="13" height="40" class = "hairStrand">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair2" width="13" height="40" class = "hairStrand">`

then,you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('hairStrand')`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Dineshkani : Are you sure that you have to write an eventListener for every individual hair ?

Comment: I wanna make my code as flexible as possible.Less is MORE!!!

Comment: @jayeshjain : Adding a class won't make your code any less flexible!

Comment: @harsha Yes, use document.getElementsByClassName() you need to iterate every class and put a listener.

Comment: @Dineshkani : Isn't that a single loop instead of writing an eventListener for 10 seperate ids

Comment: @harsha what looping do in here? It also add 10 eventListener buddy.

Comment: let me try few things in here!!!i will let you know whether your tricks worked or not??by the way..the discussion was helpful

Comment: @Dineshkani : For instance , won't the amount of code you write reduce ;)

Comment: yes,absolutely!!!but i want solution...

Comment: @Aadit M Shah:can u look at this

Comment: If you don't want 10 distinct event listeners (which wouldn't be that bad, btw) then you will have to use **event delegation** (search for it). Please notice that this has *absolutely nothing* to do with constructors or prototypical inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi:if I use constructor,than I have to create 10 instances of it u mean to say??there is no other option?

Comment: @jayeshjain: No, I just said that the events have nothing to do with constructors. Why do you want to use them? Try normal functions first.

Comment: this is my first time around with constructors,i thought maybe if i could create method and do my job in 2 lines rather than the obvious simple way,that we usually use.

Answer (score 0):

```
// one event listener for whole 'haircut'
document.getElementsByClassName('hair')[0].addEventListener('mouseover',
function(objEvent)
{
    var elImg = objEvent.target;
    if (elImg.nodeName == 'IMG')
    {
        objEvent.stopPropagation();
        console.log(elImg.getAttribute('id')); // just for debug
        // xxx.bounce(elImg) or whatever you want
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the bounce using `setTimeout`:

```
(function(){

    // "private" vars
    var delayPace = 100;// ms
    var instanceCount = 0;


    hair = function (){
        // don't need to return this if it's going 
        // to be instantiated via the new keyword
        this.delay = instanceCount * delayPace;
        instanceCount++;
    };


    hair.prototype={
        delay : 0,

        bounce : function(){
             this.stop();
             this._t = setTimeout(this._bounce, this.delay);
        },

        _bounce : function(){
            // this is were the actual magic happens
        },

        stop : function(){
            if(this.t){
                clearTimeout(this.t);
            }
            // other code to stop the animation
        }
    };
})();

// keep all your hairs in one place!
var hairs = [];

// instantiate them
hairs.push(new hair());
//...
hairs.push(new hair());

var onHover = function(){
    hairs.forEach(function(h){
        h.bounce();
    });
}
```